How to solve the Poisson equation for the source terms as the double derivative of a spherically symmetric scalar function ϕ?
I need help understanding how to solve the Poisson equation in 3D for $g_{ij}$, which incorporates the double derivative of a spherically symmetric scalar function $\phi(\textbf{x})$. Where $\textbf{x}$ is the spatial vector in 3D. The expression is given as $$\nabla^2 g_{ij} (\textbf{x}) = \frac{\partial^2\phi (\textbf{x})}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}.$$ Where $x_i$ & $x_j$ are the spatial coordinates and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $ is the partial derivative. whereas the solution is given as
$$g_{ij} (\textbf{x})=\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2} \phi (\textbf{x}) +\left(\delta_{ij}-\frac{3x_ix_j}{r^2}\right)\frac{1}{r^3}\int_0^r k^2\phi(k)dk,\tag{9.9.17}$$
where $r$ is the radial parameter due to spherical symmetry. The particular solution is given in Weinberg's book - Gravitation and Cosmology in eq 9.9.17, but not the logic. I need a logical explanation of how to derive $g_{ij}$ from the above Poisson equation. Specifically, extracting $x_i x_j$ terms out of the integral while solving for the above Poisson equation.
